# How to disable a button if the are more than 4 items selected in a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a form. It has two select lists. You can add any item from the first list to the second, through the buttons. What I want to do is to disable the first button, which adds the items, when the number of items selected is more than 4. The url where is the code is: http://www.fabulous-fi.eu/projectsevent2016/test.php.

Thanks in advance!

The code I use is:

```
function selectFillbis(){
    var html = '';

    for (var i=0; i < projectTopic.length; i++){

      html += "<option id='cod-"+i+"' value='"+ projectTopic[i] +"'>"+ projectTopic[i] +"</option>";
    }
    $('#select-primary-bis').append(html);
    $('#project-select-bis').append (html);

    $('#select-add-bis').on('click', function(){
      $('#select-primary-bis :selected').remove().appendTo('#select-secondary-bis');
    });
    $('#select-remove-bis').on('click', function(){
      $('#select-secondary-bis :selected').remove().appendTo('#select-primary-bis');
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding or removing from the selection, check the size of the added list and add the disabled class to the button if it exceeds 4.  In my example, I did this in a method called `updateDisabled` and call it whenever either the add or remove button is clicked:

```
function selectFillbis(){
        var updateDisabled = function(){
            if($('#select-secondary-bis :selected').size() > 4) 
                $("#select-add-bis").addClass('disabled'); 
            else 
                $("#select-add-bis").removeClass('disabled');
        };

    var html = '';

    for (var i=0; i < projectTopic.length; i++){

      html += "<option id='cod-"+i+"' value='"+ projectTopic[i] +"'>"+ projectTopic[i] +"</option>";
    }
    $('#select-primary-bis').append(html);
    $('#project-select-bis').append (html);

    $('#select-add-bis').on('click', function(){
      $('#select-primary-bis :selected').remove().appendTo('#select-secondary-bis');
      updateDisabled();
    });
    $('#select-remove-bis').on('click', function(){
      $('#select-secondary-bis :selected').remove().appendTo('#select-primary-bis');
      updateDisabled();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/59/)**.

You could add condition in `click` event after append item to the `select-secondary-bis` check the length then hide div `select-add-bis` if it's equal 4 :

```
$('#select-add-bis').on('click', function(){
     $('#select-primary-bis :selected').remove().appendTo('#select-secondary-bis');

     if( $('#select-secondary-bis option').length>=4 ){
         $(this).hide();
     }
});
```

Then you could show it when items are less than 4 in `select-remove-bis` click event :

```
$('#select-remove-bis').on('click', function(){
    $('#select-secondary-bis :selected').remove().appendTo('#select-primary-bis');

    if( $('#select-secondary-bis option').length<4 ){
         $('#select-add-bis').show();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn´t work. Anyway thanks for helping!